# ClickOnce application to launch a Windows 8 application

Tags: windows-8, clickonce

Is it possible to develop a Windows 8 application which can be used as a ClickOnce application - that is, a user will just hit a URL, then the Windows 8 application will get downloaded, installed and then will start running. I don't want the application to be a [Windows Store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Store) application. The application will have some simple functionality for internal company usage.

Comment: I have found few links saying that they are facing some issues in Click Once application on Winows 8 - hence i am not sure about this. I have the Application running fine as a Windows Form application. But i was thinking to make it click once through URL. I was going to create WPF application for richer UI but then thought of creating a windows 8 App. If anyone can give throw some lights here, it will be really very useful. - Thanks

Comment: You can't use ClickOnce with a "metro app", but you can take the same application that you can also run on Windows XP or Windows 7 and run it on Windows 8. I've responded more fully below.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the version of Windows 8 you are talking about. You can't run a ClickOnce app on Windows 8 RT. You can run it on Windows 8. You need to be aware of the issue with the Smart Screen Filter. You have to sign the executable now, which you can do with a pre-publish or post-build directive. If you do not have a signing certificate from a CA, you will have to educate your users to click "more info" when the installation is interrupted by the Smart Screen Filter. For VSTO applications, you *must* have a valid certificate; it won't work at all on Windows 8 if it is not signed, or is signed with a self-created certificate.